# Type.GetProperty retunring null, when i expect it to return a valid column PropertyINfo

Tags: c#, reflection

Here is the code I'm calling

```
        PropertyInfo targetColumn;
        targetColumn = targetType.GetProperty("CtrId");
```

Here is the Class

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace JCDCHelper.CV
{
    [DataContract, Serializable]
    public class CenterAllActiveCV
    {
        [DataMember]
        [XmlElement( DataType = "long" )]
        public Int64 CtrId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [XmlElement( DataType = "string", IsNullable = true )]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I'm expecting targetColumn to be a valid PropertyInfo, but I'm getting null.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks,

Eric-

Comment: I tried the code and it worked fine here. Is `targetType` assigned with `typeof(CenterAllActiveCV)`?

Comment: Is the actual type a subtype perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird,

I recreated the CV file from scratch, and it works perfectly now.
I guess I'll chalk it up to "invisible characters" in the CV...

Always leaves me wtih an unsettled feeling. :)

Cal-

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your code just fine. How are you getting a Type reference?

```
Type targetType = typeof(CenterAllActiveCV);
var property = targetType.GetProperty("CtrId");
```

This worked for me...